# This query runs perfact in SQL but giving error in PHP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, zend-framework

I have one sql query like this :

```
 select * from tbl_ServiceRequest SR left join tbl_Events e on s.SRId = e.SRId where CustomerId = 65 and convert(nvarchar(10),s.CreatedDate,120) > (select convert(nvarchar(10),OrganisationCycleDate,120) from tbl_OrganizationDetail where OrgId = (select OrgId from Organization))))
```

When i run it into the sql server 2008 than it runs perfact and gives the correct records.

But i am using PHP with zend framework and its giving this error in php :

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

there is not any ';' in my query.

The problem is in the second condition. if i will remove the second condition than its not giving any error. Second condition is :

```
 and convert(nvarchar(10),s.CreatedDate,120) > (select convert(nvarchar(10),OrganisationCycleDate,120) from tbl_OrganizationDetail where OrgId = (select OrgId from Organization))))
```

Its giving me this error when i try to download pdf of these records. I am using FPDF library for it. But it is error of SQL Server only.

Can anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: And you seems to have two extra `))` at the end.

Comment: SRId is Primary key in service request table and ref key in event table.

Comment: @mishik : ya i removed that but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_ServiceRequest s
LEFT JOIN tbl_Events e ON s.SRId = e.SRId
WHERE CustomerId = 65
  AND convert(nvarchar(10),s.CreatedDate,120) >
    (SELECT convert(nvarchar(10),OrganisationCycleDate,120)
     FROM tbl_OrganizationDetail
     WHERE OrgId =
         (SELECT OrgId
          FROM Organization));
```

Renaming your tbl_ServiceRequest as `s` ***not*** `SR` I guess.

Comment: can you add the attrs of your two tables?

Comment: now its giving this error : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

Comment: do you have `;` at the end of your query?

Comment: i use sql a lot from command prompt and it always terminates with `;`

Comment: ok i tried with ; also but still same error : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33327/discussion-between-mausami-and-a-s-roma)

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved. There isn't any problem with sql.

There is a problem with php.

```
I just replace "&gt;" with > and "&lt;" with < in my query and it runs perfactly.
```

Thanks a lot A.S. Roma for your help..